# how to create vanity url in java web applications?

Tags: java, url, jakarta-ee

If we have a person-directory application, 
where we can check the details of a specific person (for example, person with id 239) at

```
http://person-directory.com/detail.jsp?id=239
```

how can we create vanity urls in it?
i.e. instead of typing the above url, we use

```
http://person-directory.com/julius
```

to open the detail page of person with id 239 and username julius.

Thanks

Umar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you'll have to

1. map a servlet to the root context (i.e. http://person-directory.com/)
2. use the [HttpServletRequest.getPathInfo()](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29) and extract the name from the URL your servlet has been called with
3. use that name to do a lookup in your backend datasource

Note that a better URL may be http://person-directory/username/julius. Then you could map your UserServlet to http://person-directory/username and provide other servlets on other URLs.

Comment: This sounds like one way to do things. Before step 3, you could have a list of names to exclude as being part of the web site.

Comment: Yes. I think a better URL would be http://hostname/user/julius. I will amend the answer to include this

Answer (score 2):

You could also try to use the url-rewrite filter: http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/. Of course, you have to change your code to query by username instead of id.